# jQuery closest input field

Tags: jquery

I have a constructions like this one:

```
<div class="form-group dynamic-group">
   <label id="field_name_539" class=" control-label list-label dynamic-label">Untitled
     <span id="field_required_539" class="field-required" style="color: #FF0000; ">*</span>
   </label>
  <div id="field_539" class=" list-field">
    <input class="form-control dynamic-control field-text input-block-level" type="text" value="" placeholder="" name="Untitled">
    <span id="field_description_539" class="help-block">Some help text goes here</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I can get a value of input field which closest to ".field-required"? I try to do so, but it does not work:

```
$(".field-required:visible").each(function() {
  alert($(this).closest(":input").val());
});
```

Comment: input is not parent of `field-required`

Answer (score 3):

`input` is not parent of `field-required`

Use

```
$(".field-required:visible").each(function() {
  alert($(this).closest(".dynamic-group").find(":input").val());
});
```

Comment: @RedOctober, Great :)

Answer (score 1):

USe like this, if you have many `inputs` in that `form-group dynamic-group`

```
$(".field-required:visible").each(function () {
    alert($(this).parent().next().find(":input").val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Go up the tree and then down:

```
$(".field-required").parents('.form-group').find('input').each(function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```